# php session changes value

Tags: php, session-cookies, session-variables, session-state

the values of my session changes after i refresh the page or go other pages

i have tried to insert some `echo` to my code to see where it's changed, at the beginning of the page:

```
   <?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['type'];
    require_once 'dbc.php';
```

at the end of the code:

```
   </body>
    </html>
    <?php echo $_SESSION['type'];?>
```

it prints the true value when i am setting it , changing the value when refreshing the page, knowing that there's just `session_start()` between the two `echo` line.

Answer (score 0):

just reinstalling Xampp solved the problem